# undefined error on accessing json/object from laravel controller to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am trying to manipulate an object/ json return from the controller in ajax jquery success method.

My codes looks like this -

On controller:

```
$product_code=$_GET['p_id'];        
$productdata=Product::select('id','product_name','unit_measure','cost_price'
  )->where('product_code','=',$product_code)->get();    
    return $productdata;    //return object         
    return $productdata->toJson();//return json
```

On view(ajax call):

```
success: function(data){ 
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data["product_name"]);
  //for json [ console.log(data.product_name);
},
```

Data has been received successfully but don't know why I am getting undefined error for accessing those data as above.
Thanks in advance!

This is what I am exactly getting when trying with json. Output in the console:

```
[{"id":3,"product_name":"computer network","unit_measure":"piece","cost_price":500}]
undefined
```

Comment: you can try using console.log(data[0].product_name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is undefined because response object is in array, this should work:

```
console.log(data.0.product_name);
```

Comment: not working for me !! :( even tried console.log(data[0].product_name);

Comment: what you get when console.log(data.0) ?
You can also try loop result like $.each(data, function(k,v) { console.info(v); }); and see what you get